# $formatNumber outputs NaN when used in table array

Tags: adobe-documentgeneration

I'm applying number formatting to a PDF document, which works fine in a 'parent' record in the JSON data, but fails when used inside a table. How can I get the $formatNumber expression to work inside an array of data?

The data is being merged into an invoice document, and in one of the columns of the "Invoice Line Items" I'd like to format the number with the expression $formatNumber, '#,###.00'.

Here is the merge syntax in my word document:

This formatting works fine for the parent data:
{{ $formatNumber(QuoteLineItems.totalSize, '#,###.00') }}

This formatting fails when used inside a table (the output in the PDF si "NaN")
{{ $formatNumber(QuoteLineItems.records.AmountNet, '#,###.00') }}

[Image: Comparison of Success vs Failure syntax](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8t4P8.png)

[Image: PDF Output contains NaN in table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2svQ.png)

here is the sample input data I am using inside the word plugin document tagger:

```
{
    "QuoteLineItems":
    {
        "records":
        [
            {
                "AmountGross": 47897,
                "AmountNet": 44556,
                "Name": "Sample Charges"
            },
            {
                "AmountGross": 4968,
                "AmountNet": 4621,
                "Name": "Sample 2 Charges"
            }
        ],
        "done": true,
        "totalSize": 2
    },
    "Name": "Sample Invoice"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the delay in answering this. This is a known bug (I'm going to check on the status). For now I suggest doing your number format in your code before sending it to the API. If that doesn't make sense, let me know and I'll clarify.

Comment: Great, thanks for the update. We'll do some server-side formatting in the meantime. As we get more dynamic with our documents it would be great to have control over this in the template.

Comment: Absolutely - it's a known issue I hope to see corrected soon.